# How to get a list of items include in a class from Entity Framework database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with my application. I cannot get from the database a object where there's a list in it. I'm really not good in Entity Framework so sorry if this is a really big mistake.

```
public List<Recipe> GetRecipes(Cook cook)
    {
        List<Recipe> L_Recipes = new List<Recipe>();
        Cook Cook = dbc.DbCook.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Nickname == cook.Nickname);
        L_Recipes = Cook.ListRecipes;
        return L_Recipes;
    }
```

and this is the `Recipe` class:

```
  public class Recipe
{
    //Attributes
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public float CostPrice { get; set; }
    public float SellingPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<Ingredient> ListIngredients { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> ListComments { get; set; }
    public Schedule Schedules { get; set; }
    //Builder
    public Recipe(string name, string type)
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
        Date = DateTime.Now;
        ListIngredients = new List<Ingredient>();
        Schedules = new Schedule();
    }
    public Recipe(string name,string type,float costPrice,float SellingPrice,DateTime Date,List<Ingredient> ListIngredients,List<Comment> ListComments,Schedule Schedules)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Type = type;
        this.CostPrice = costPrice;
        this.SellingPrice = SellingPrice;
        this.Date = Date;
        this.ListIngredients = ListIngredients;
        this.ListComments = ListComments;
        this.Schedules = Schedules;
    }
    public Recipe() { ListIngredients = new List<Ingredient>(); }
    //Methods
    public void AddIngredient(Ingredient i)
    {
        ListIngredients.Add(i);
    }
    public float CalculCostPrice()
    {
        float cost = 0;
        foreach (Ingredient ing in ListIngredients)
        {
            cost += ing.CalculCostIngredient();
        }
        return cost;
    }
    public float CalculSellingPrice()
    {
        return (float)(CalculCostPrice()*1.05);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string SP = string.Format("{0:00.00}", SellingPrice);
        return $"{Name} for {SP} euros added the {Date.ToString()}";
    }
}
```

The problem is I received the info of the recipe but not the list in it.

It's in ASP.NET

Include code:

```
        public List<Recipe> GetRecipes(Cook cook)
    {
        List<Recipe> L_Recipes = new List<Recipe>();
        Cook Cook = dbc.DbCook.Include(c => c.ListRecipes).singleOrDefault(c => c.Nickname == cook.Nickname);
        L_Recipes = Cook.ListRecipes;
        return L_Recipes;
    }
```

Comment: U need to use Include. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: I have tried this and this is what I received:Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it's not a delegate type /I'm not on ASP.NET Core

Comment: Can u post your code with 'Include' option?

Comment: Okay. But i'm not on ASP.NET Core

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode - please **DO NOT** post screenshots of your code - post the **actual** code (as text) inside your message and properly format it (using the `{ .. }` button)

Comment: Okay sorry, it's my first post here :/

Comment: @thelittlewozniak to use `Include` with a lambda expression you need to add `using System.Data.Entity;` to the source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to https://stackoverflow.com/users/395675/philip-smith and https://stackoverflow.com/users/5748194/felipe-deveza
So the answer is Use the Include and add an using
include:`public List<Recipe> GetRecipes(Cook cook)
    {
        List<Recipe> L_Recipes = new List<Recipe>();
        Cook Cook = dbc.DbCook.Include(c => c.ListRecipes).singleOrDefault(c => c.Nickname == cook.Nickname);
        L_Recipes = Cook.ListRecipes;
        return L_Recipes;
    }`
and the using: `using System.Data.Entity;`